# How can I compare two lists of numbers and their ascending orders?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers. And then some slight changes are applied to each of the numbers. I want to check if their ascending order has changed. Is there a quick and elegant way to achieve this?

My current approach:

```
pack_before = list(zip(range(len(list_before)), list_before))
pack_after = list(zip(range(len(list_after)), list_after))

pack_before.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
pack_after.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

sorted_idx_before = np.array([pack[0] for pack in pack_before])
sorted_idx_after = np.array([pack[0] for pack in pack_after])

sum((int(e0==e1) for (e0,e1) in zip(sorted_idx_before, sorted_idx_after)))
```

I feel that I make the problem more complicated then it should be..

Comment: How long is your list? It may be as simple as checking if `sorted(L) == L`.

Comment: Give example of what you want.Show what you have tried

Comment: not so long, about 300 numbers.

Comment: I'm a new learner. My approach is complicated. 1)  index both lists (before and after changes) 2) sort the lists with indices 3) pick out their indices and then count the differences. I hope there is a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: apologize and changed.

Answer (score 1):

This works if the lists are numpy arrays

```
isSorted = (list_of_numbers[:-1] <= list_of_numbers[1:]).all()
```

---

Convert to numpy with:

```
import numpy as np

list_of_numbers = np.asarray(list_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to check whether the modified list is sorted in linear time:

```
all(x <= y for x,y in zip(yourList, yourList[1:]))
```

Comment: Also, by using the `pairwise` itertools recipe you can do this in linear time and constant rather than linear space.

Comment: @abarnert What exactly is the status of a "recipe" in python ecosystem? Small-scale "design patterns" not included in the library?